# How to implement custom texture formats in Android?

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es2

**What I know:**
Android can load PNG, BMP, WEBP,... via BitmapFactory.

**What I want to achive:**
Load my own 2D file format (e.g. 1-bit texture with a 1-bit alpha channel) and output a RGBA8888 texture.

**Question:**
Is there any interface to achieve this?(or any other way)

**The resulting image is used as a texture for a 3D model.**

***Why would you do that?**
Saving phone memory and download bandwidth while expanding the texture at runtime to RAM seems reasonable for very simple textures.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load texture with glTexImage2D 
You will pass texel format and pointer to texel array
texel is textures pixels

```
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
    TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT,
    0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureArray);
```